# IISNode caching old file names and I can't seem to update it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, caching, iisnode

Hello and thank you in advance.
This may be a rather simple scenario, however, I am new to Nodejs.
I have a main script which I am calling from javascript using IISNode. Everything has worked great until I decided to rename a dependency file.

Files involved:

- `embed.js` <- main script
- `dev2.js` <- required custom script by `embed.js`
  which reads this json file
- `fred.json` renamed to `chartio.json`

`embed.js` code relevant to issue:

```js
var http = require('http');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var dashinfo = require('./dev2');

var ORGANIZATION_SECRET = dashinfo.getkey();
var ORG_ID = dashinfo.getorgid();
```

`dev2.js` code relevant to issue:

```js
var mariadb = require('mariadb');
var connectioninfo = require('./chartio.json');

module.exports = {
  getkey: function () {
    return connectioninfo.connection.apikey;
  },
  getorgid: function () {
    return connectioninfo.connection.orgid;
  },
```

and finally, I have my `charti0.json` file which I cannot post due to sensitive data.
I assure you that everything was working until I renamed `fred.json` to `chartio.json`.

I have looked online to see if there is a way to clear the cache but I couldn't find anything that seemed to work, though I am a novice. I also looked at logs. I tried running this in IE and Chrome

This is what I see logged from the error:

```js
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:


Error: Cannot find module './fred.json'
Require stack:
- C:\xxx\xxx\GPS411\node\dev2.js
- C:\xxx\xxx\GPS411\node\embed.js
- C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Omnitracs\sylectus-trunk\GPS411\node\dev2.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I was able to get this working by doing an old fashion workstation reboot. I changed the filename again to test if the issue returns and it seems to recognize the file changes now. I guess I was just stuck in cache-land, but now I'm free. Thanks for your consideration.